# Google Maps Fusion Table layer doesn't apply conditional styles based on the text column

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I'd like to apply different marker styles depends on the column with three different string values. Query works fine, it uses FT styles if no styles defined in the script, but if there is conditional logic implemented - map gets the layer with "Data still maybe loading" label and no error produced.

The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var map,layer;
        google.load('maps', '3', { other_params: 'sensor=false' });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
        var cp = new google.maps.LatLng(42.87, 74.57);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: cp,
          zoom: 7,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });
        layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: { select: 'Locations (oblast, rayon, village)', from: '2825956' },
          // if the styles definition below exists map doesn't get any data layer applied
          styles: [
            { markerOptions: { iconName: 'wht_blank'} },
                { where: "'Thematic area' = 'Environment and Sustainable development'", markerOptions: { iconName: 'grn_blank' }},
                { where: "'Thematic area' = 'Democratic Governance Programme'", markerOptions: { iconName: 'blu_blank' }},
                { where: "'Thematic area' = 'Poverty Reduction'", markerOptions: { iconName: 'red_blank' }}
            ]
        });
        layer.setMap(map);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool to see that you're using FT styling. It's a great feature.

There's only one problem with your code. The column you're looking for in your table is actually called `Locations`.

Change your query to this:

```
query: { select: 'Locations', from: '2825956' },
```

and everything works.

Comment: Thanks, it works much better although not for all markers for some reason - appr half of them getting default white marker even though every row in a table is categorized. Will need to perform some research here... BTW, I'm wondering why it should be addressed as Locations? Actual name of the column is actually 'Locations (oblast, rayon, village)', does it mean that Locations is just a reserved word for Fusion tables? Or it just takes the first word from the name of the column if it contain spaces?

Comment: Disregard second part of the comment above, column header has been changed by my co-editor to "Locations" - it was the reason of confusion